# How to configure nginx request routing

Tags: reactjs, nginx

I am writing an application consisting of 3 sub-applications.
Front end - React Dotsupna at all addresses except those already taken.
Admin panel - React. Dotsupna at /admin
Server - Java Spring Available at /api
Set up CICD. And each pod application is deployed in a docker container.
I ran into a problem that when trying to open the admin panel, the server looks for static files in the front end (/assets), and since they are not there, it displays the page incorrectly. Please tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: You should rebuild your admin app according to your URI prefix; [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#building-for-relative-paths) is the official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to create a reverse nginx proxy with docker and request to that container so the reverse proxy resolve how to find each container depend on its url.

**nginxreverseproxy.conf**

```
# https://www.nginx.com/blog/using-free-ssltls-certificates-from-lets-encrypt-with-nginx/

# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;
    
    ##
    # `gzip` Settings
    #
    #
    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_min_length 256;
    gzip_types
      application/atom+xml
      application/geo+json
      application/javascript
      application/x-javascript
      application/json
      application/ld+json
      application/manifest+json
      application/rdf+xml
      application/rss+xml
      application/xhtml+xml
      application/xml
      font/eot
      font/otf
      font/ttf
      image/svg+xml
      text/css
      text/javascript
      text/plain
      text/xml;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
#   include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf;


server {
        server_name site.com;
        location / {
                proxy_pass      http://frontendcontainer:port;
                proxy_set_header        Host    $host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
 
        }
}
server {
        server_name adminapi.site.com;
        location / {
                proxy_pass      http://adminapicontainer:port;
                proxy_set_header        Host    $host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                client_max_body_size    100M;
        }
}
server {
        server_name admin.site.com;
        location / {
                proxy_pass      http://frontendcontainer:port;
                proxy_set_header        Host    $host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                client_max_body_size    100M;
        }
}

}
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
nginx-reverse:
    container_name: nginx-reverseproxy
    networks:
      mybackendnetwork:
        ipv4_address: 172.30.0.106
    image: 'nginx:latest'
    volumes:
      - ./nginxreverseproxy.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
    restart: always
```